# Making the for loop append on all the dataset

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I'm trying to make the for loop append on all the data set which is from the range of `(0,8675)` but it keeps getting error just working with 1 row

```py
def convert_emoticons(text):
    for emot in EMOTICONS:
        text = re.sub(u'('+emot+')', "_".join(EMOTICONS[emot].replace(",","").split()), text)
    return text

text = (dataset['posts'][0])
convert_emoticons(text)
```

Comment: please provide sample input data

Answer (score 1):

Try using just `emot`:

```
def convert_emoticons(text):
    for emot in EMOTICONS:
        text = re.sub(u'('+emot+')', "_".join(emot.replace(",","").split()), text)
    return text

text = (dataset['posts'][0])
convert_emoticons(text)
```